# Angular : How to check if a row exists in another Component

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 10 .

I have got two independent Components say EmployessList  and Component B .

I am displaying a table in EmployessList  using a ngFor directive . While displaying I need to check whether this row (FirstName ) consists in Component B or not ?? (FYI , an another set of Employees exists as an array in Component B )

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the solutions is to inject on a service to those components and in that service filter Employees and give it to those components.

Comment: i guess , u mean to say , use a shared service for communication ?
but a two way communication possible ??

EmployeeList Component sends a row and component B reacts to send true or false depending on it exists or not

Comment: @Lavanya i think , its better to filter data before initial EmployeeList Component.
and filter EmployeeList data with Component B data .is it possible ?

Comment: @Lavanya you can set and store Component B data in shared service and write method to check row with that data and return boolean then call that method for all of your EmployessList Component.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you need to share data between 2 different component. After you got the data from "EmployeesList" in "component B" you can compare and manipulate things that you want to display.
There is a few ways, I think that the proper way in this situation is to use **BehaviorSubject**.